# Anyone using Emacs as front end of Mathematica?

Tags: emacs, wolfram-mathematica

So much I'm missing the Emacs power when I (have to) stay inside Mathematica editor. I saw a few mathematicas-mode, but they are all outdated... Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe here? http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/6039/363